# How to create a page template of solid and dotted lines for handwriting practice?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, page-layout, line-height

I am looking to make a tear off children's handbook for writing practice of words. I wanted to know how make "dotted lines" or "four lines" template that is to the standards of what child handbooks have.

- Is there any template in illustrator or InDesign?
- Is there a specific measurement between those lines?

[image: Dotted lines sample]

Comment: I'm not sure how official these are, and I'll go with Joojaa on this (standards must vary among different countries), but [here is a list of writing paper templates](http://www.first-school.ws/theme/printables/writing-paper/handwriting.htm) you can use to measure the distance between the lines and create then your own. They seem to be divided according to kid's age.

Comment: One of the reasons they would vary would be ease of measurement and availability. The optimal size must have some considerable spread because we are talking of a group with at minimum 1 year age difference. So the size will have no exact value therefore designer has good choice. Americans allmost universally would be based on inches while europeans on mm. Most likely you would use a size that is commonly used in paper with grids found locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In illustrator do this (see footnotes for InDesign changes):

1. Draw a line with the line tool
2. Select the line and right click on it and choose **Transform → Move...**

   In the vertical slot type how much you ant each line separated. Then hit **Copy**.
3. Hit **ctrl + D**<sup>†</sup> to make a third line (with equal spacing).
4. Color the strokes and apply dashing in the stroke palette.
5. select all and chose **rmb menu→  Transform → Move...** again

   It should remember your previous value, type 3* before the measurement and hit the **Copy** button (do not press enter).
6. Hit **ctrl + D**<sup>†</sup> repeatedly until you have enough lines.

#### Ammendum

What should the gap be? Locally it is easy to come by paper with a grid size with gaps of 15, 10 and 7mm<sup>‡</sup> (and also 5mm but not used in local schools). So invariably its a good idea to make the grid match these. There is however some considerable variation region by region. And even generation to generation.

Check your local school plan for the ideal in your region. what is considered best varies country by country.

<sup>**†**</sup> in InDesign use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>

<sup>**‡**</sup> 7 mm being roughly half of a 15 mm

Comment: So there is no specific measurement between distance of lines? As they are children handbook for teaching them how to write.

Comment: @Nofel you need to come up with the measurement yourself, you're the designer. The measurement that is optimal varies by culture so different language areas have different ideas of how big letters should be. In fact also have different ideas of how to measure distances and what letters look like. See your local teaching plan. What's appropriate for my region is not appropriate to you. Don't over analyze this, writing is far less uniform than you think.

Comment: Added some comments on the size. Hard to say anything more quantitative as we dont know where you are located on this globe.

Comment: I m from Pakistan and I think we follow British.

Comment: which software you mention the above method of?

Comment: Illustrator but same idea works in InDesign with modification that ctrl+D is alt+ctrl+4

Comment: @DumbNic But see us mechanical engineers tend to avoid half mm slots, because it makes measurement hard, so we would prefer 5, 6, 7, 8, and 10, mm as the 9 somehow feels off and 7 is only acceptable as half of 15, 16 being preferable. :P